# mysql sum with group by query need specific sum

Tags: mysql

**Run code in** http://rextester.com/OZKM95674

I am trying to come up with an fast and easy way to get the sum of quantity for all variations of an item but also include data such as all tags (comma seperated) and one of the images for an item (doesn't matter which one). There are many tables involve shown below:

Query 1: This query below gets the data I want for quantity but is missing data I need for my application (see query 2).

```
SELECT  phppos_items.item_id,
        phppos_items.name, 
        SUM(phppos_location_item_variations.quantity) as quantity
FROM `phppos_items`
LEFT JOIN `phppos_item_variations` 
       ON `phppos_item_variations`.`item_id` = `phppos_items`.`item_id` 
LEFT JOIN `phppos_location_item_variations` 
       ON `phppos_location_item_variations`.`item_variation_id` = `phppos_item_variations`.`id` 
      and `phppos_location_item_variations`.`location_id` = 1
GROUP BY `phppos_items`.`item_id`
```

Result:

```
+---------+------+----------+
| item_id | name | quantity |
+---------+------+----------+
|       1 | TEST |       10 |
+---------+------+----------+
```

Query 2: But in the application I actually need more data about an item such as tags and one image (could be many just need one). I need the exact output as below but instead of the quantity being 60 I need it to be 20 like before. I know the reason this is happening because when I do group by; there is more than one row because there are 3 tags and 1 image.

```
SELECT  phppos_items.item_id, 
        phppos_items.name, SUM(phppos_location_item_variations.quantity) as quantity,
       `phppos_item_images`.`image_id` as `image_id`, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT phppos_tags.name) as tags
FROM `phppos_items`
LEFT JOIN `phppos_item_variations` 
       ON `phppos_item_variations`.`item_id` = `phppos_items`.`item_id` 
LEFT JOIN `phppos_location_item_variations` 
       ON `phppos_location_item_variations`.`item_variation_id` = `phppos_item_variations`.`id` 
      and `phppos_location_item_variations`.`location_id` = 1
LEFT JOIN `phppos_items_tags` 
       ON `phppos_items_tags`.`item_id` = `phppos_items`.`item_id` 
LEFT JOIN `phppos_tags` 
       ON `phppos_tags`.`id` = `phppos_items_tags`.`tag_id` 
LEFT JOIN `phppos_item_images` 
       ON `phppos_items`.`item_id` = `phppos_item_images`.`item_id` 
WHERE `phppos_items`.`deleted` = 0
  AND `phppos_items`.`system_item` = 0 
GROUP BY `phppos_items`.`item_id`


+---------+------+----------+----------+--------------------+
| item_id | name | quantity | image_id | tags               |
+---------+------+----------+----------+--------------------+
|       1 | TEST |       60 |        1 | test,test 2,test 3 |
+---------+------+----------+----------+--------------------+
```

What is an efficient way to get all this data in one query?

Sample data:

```
phppos_items:
+---------+------+
| item_id | name |
+---------+------+
|       1 | TEST |
+---------+------+

phppos_item_variations:
+---------+----+
| item_id | id |
+---------+----+
|       1 |  1 |
+---------+----+

phppos_location_item_variations:
+-------------------+----------+
| item_variation_id | quantity |
+-------------------+----------+
|                 1 |       10 |
+-------------------+----------+

phppos_tags:
+--------+----+
| name   | id |
+--------+----+
| test   |  1 |
| test 2 |  2 |
| test 3 |  3 |
+--------+----+

phppos_items_tags:
+---------+--------+
| item_id | tag_id |
+---------+--------+
|       1 |      1 |
|       1 |      2 |
|       1 |      3 |
+---------+--------+

phppos_item_images:
+---------+----------+
| item_id | image_id |
+---------+----------+
|       1 |        1 |
|       1 |        4 |
+---------+----------+
```

Tables involved

```
CREATE TABLE `phppos_items` (
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `item_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `deleted` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `system_item` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `item_number` (`item_number`),
  KEY `deleted` (`deleted`),
  KEY `deleted_system_item` (`deleted`,`system_item`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |

CREATE TABLE `phppos_item_variations` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `item_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `phppos_item_variations_ibfk_1` (`item_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `phppos_item_variations_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`item_id`) REFERENCES `phppos_items` (`item_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |

 CREATE TABLE `phppos_location_item_variations` (
  `item_variation_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `location_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reorder_level` decimal(23,10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `replenish_level` decimal(23,10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`item_variation_id`,`location_id`),
  KEY `phppos_item_attribute_location_values_ibfk_2` (`location_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `phppos_item_attribute_location_values_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`item_variation_id`) REFERENCES `phppos_item_variations` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `phppos_item_attribute_location_values_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`location_id`) REFERENCES `phppos_locations` (`location_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |

CREATE TABLE `phppos_items_tags` (
  `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tag_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`,`tag_id`),
  KEY `phppos_items_tags_ibfk_2` (`tag_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `phppos_items_tags_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`item_id`) REFERENCES `phppos_items` (`item_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `phppos_items_tags_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`) REFERENCES `phppos_tags` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |


CREATE TABLE `phppos_tags` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ecommerce_tag_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `deleted` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `tag_name` (`name`),
  KEY `deleted` (`deleted`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |

CREATE TABLE `phppos_item_images` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `alt_text` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `item_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_variation_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ecommerce_image_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `phppos_item_images_ibfk_1` (`item_id`),
  KEY `phppos_item_images_ibfk_2` (`image_id`),
  KEY `phppos_item_images_ibfk_3` (`item_variation_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `phppos_item_images_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`item_id`) REFERENCES `phppos_items` (`item_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `phppos_item_images_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`image_id`) REFERENCES `phppos_app_files` (`file_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `phppos_item_images_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`item_variation_id`) REFERENCES `phppos_item_variations` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |
```

Comment: Does this query return one specific item, or all items? If one specific, I would go with subqueries, if multiple, maybe temporary table and "UPDATE ... LEFT JOIN" it with additional data

Comment: It is a rare occasion when you can aggregate on multiple, unrelated one-to-many (or many-to-many) relations; in almost all cases, those relations must be handled separately using subqueries. _Do your summing in a subquery, and then join those results to the tags...and then join those results to the images._

Comment: It returns all items

Comment: Can you not do something like SELECT id, MAX(col1), MAX(col2), SUM(col3), GROUP_CONCAT(col4) FROM tables GROUP BY id? I mean use MAX or MIN to get a value for columns where you only want an arbitrary value. (I don't know if this meets your requirements since the result wouldn't necessarily match a real row, but if you only care about the columns independently...)

Comment: I don't think min/max would work since they still end up in the join as a group.

Comment: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I have read this document before and thought I did a pretty good job on this. I reduced the query down the the minimal amount to show the problem I am having. What are you not clear on?

Comment: Maybe is Complete and Verifiable. But certainly isn't Minimal. For example every table has `phppos` prefix and your create table include fields not need it on the query. That is info we dont need to create the query but make us waste time reading. And if you prepare a working demo in rextester save us the time to do it for you.

Comment: here is example in rextester http://rextester.com/OZKM95674

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said your first query already works so now you need get the remaining information

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/ZNIGZ83818)**

```
SELECT Q1.*, Q2.tags, Q3.image_id
FROM (  SELECT  phppos_items.item_id,
                phppos_items.name, 
                SUM(phppos_location_item_variations.quantity) as quantity
        FROM `phppos_items`
        LEFT JOIN `phppos_item_variations` 
               ON `phppos_item_variations`.`item_id` = `phppos_items`.`item_id` 
        LEFT JOIN `phppos_location_item_variations` 
               ON `phppos_location_item_variations`.`item_variation_id` = `phppos_item_variations`.`id` 
              and `phppos_location_item_variations`.`location_id` = 1
        GROUP BY `phppos_items`.`item_id` ) as Q1
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT i.item_id,
                   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t.name) as tags
            FROM phppos_items i
            LEFT JOIN phppos_items_tags it
              ON i.item_id = it.item_id
            LEFT JOIN phppos_tags t
              ON it.tag_id = t.id
            GROUP BY i.item_id        
           ) as Q2
  ON Q1.item_id = Q2.item_id
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT item_id, MIN(image_id) as image_id
            FROM phppos_item_images
            GROUP BY item_id 
           ) as Q3
  ON Q1.item_id = Q3.item_id
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Works great! I merged it into my application and changed parts of it...How performant is this?

Comment: Checking again you could include q3 part into q1. For perfomance you have to check explain result. [**MySQL**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15371/how-do-i-get-the-execution-plan-for-a-view)

Comment: How would I include q3 into q1?

Comment: The quantity went to 20; I don't think there is a way because joining that table adds an extra row in group

Comment: You are right. My bad. I roll back to previous version